# Parse Cloud Function response not being received

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I have written a Parse cloud function which sends back a JSON response on execution. However, I am unable to receive that response back into Unity3d.

The parse cloud function is as follows:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("SearchQuery2", function(request, response) {
var Algolia = require('cloud/algoliasearch-node');
console.log('Alogolia dictionary required');
var client  = new Algolia('APIid','APIKey');
var index   = client.initIndex('projects');
var SearchedObjectIDs = [];


index.search(request.params.searchThis, function(error, content) { 

  if (content ==null) {
      console.log("error here");
      response.error("nothing found");
  }
  else {
      console.log("success here");
      console.log(content.hits);

      response.success(content.hits);

  };
  ;


}); 
});
```

Everything gets printed fine in the log.

However, when I try to call the results in Unity3d using the cloud call function:

```
private IEnumerator PayPoints( )
{

    IDictionary<string, object> searchText = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "searchThis", "hsr" }
    };

    Task cloudFunctionTask = ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<JSONObject>("SearchQuery2", searchText)

        .ContinueWith(t =>
      {
            Debug.Log("AABBCC");

            if(t.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.Log(t.Exception.GetBaseException().Message + "error here");
            }
            Debug.Log(t.Result);
        }
        );


    Debug.Log("We are running the cloud function now ... ");
    while (! cloudFunctionTask.IsCompleted) yield return null;
    Debug.Log(" .... we ran the cloud function OK !!!");

    yield break;
}
```

I get the following error in the log:

```
Exception of type 'System.AggregateException' was thrown.error here
```

Inner Exceptions are:

```
Error message Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.parse.com:443 
Error code: OtherCause
```

Server log here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nJ4g.jpg

Am i missing something here?

Comment: use try and catch on your continue

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: What does the server log say? What is the response it sends back?

Comment: This is the server log
http://imgur.com/1UCsAIN

Comment: [AggregateException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) combines multiple inner exceptions into a single outer exception.  What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception, including all inner exceptions?

Comment: Updated the post with output of the inner exceptions.